# Fastest way to find the order of x in a Finite Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Working on $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, I want to find the less $n$ than $f(x)=x^8+x^6+x^5+x+1$ is a divisor of $x^n -1$. This is the same than finding the order of $[x]$ in the quotient $\frac{\mathbb{F}_2[x]}{<f(x)>}$, isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{256}$. One way is trying $[x^n]$ for every $n | 255$. Are there any other ways to find the order?

Comment: $255=3\cdot5\cdot17$ has very few factors, so this particular case is not really a problem. If $x^a\neq1$ for all $a\in\{255/3,255/5,255/17\}$ you can conclude that the order is $255$. Actually as you need to know that $f(x)$ is irreducible anyway, you can drop $255/17=15$ from that list. For if $x^{15}\equiv1\pmod{f(x)}$ then $f(x)$ is a product of disinct polynomials of degrees $1,2,4$.

Comment: Judging from [this MO question with associated anwer and comments](https://mathoverflow.net/q/121725/39640), this seems like a hard problem.